# Sphinx alphabetical pagination / navigation menu

Tags: pagination, sphinx, alphabetical

I need to do a pagination / navigation menu in Sphinx

*(for signs) 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

And to filter the results.

In the "A" page - just the results starting with "A"

Thanks

Comment: Is this really about sphinxsearch? Sphinx is a name of a search indexer, but also a python documentation framework (as well as a Speach processing toolkit) - need clarification which you mean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But if you do mean sphinxsearch, something like this

```
sql_query = SELECT id, name, ORD(IF(ORD(name) BETWEEN 48 AND 57 OR ORD(UPPER(name)) BETWEEN 65 AND 90, UPPER(SUBSTRING(name,0,1)), '*')) AS ord, ...
sql_attr_uint = ord
```

Would give you a numeric attribute representing the first letter of the name. Can be used with **setFilter** to only return results matching that value.

Can even be used with **setGroupBy** to get the number of results matching each ordinal.

REF: http://www.asciitable.com/

--

Edit to add: Using a Integer Attribute - having got an integer via the mysql ORD function, because attr str2ordinal (nor string attributes for that matter!) allow filtering. Converting yourself to an integer like this allows filtering.

Eg to get only 'A' results, could do

```
$cl->setFilter('ord',array(ord('A')));
```

This works because php's ord function works the same way as mysql.

Comment: Hello.
I was thinking on something like this:

sql_query = SELECT id, name, LEFT(UPPER(name), 1) AS first_letter, ...
sql_attr_str2ordinal = first_letter

(UPPER(name) NOT REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]]') (all non alphanumeric - grouped in a single "*" category)
(UPPER(name) REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]]')

* 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

And I want to filter after that by "first_letter"
$result = $cl->Query( $search where name starts with "A");

Comment: Or to set a filter:
something like: $cl->SetFilter ("first_letter", "A" );

Comment: Another thing:
To make the firsta characters loop, i need to make 2 queries because the first one has a 20 elements limit and I want to make the alphabetical pagination for total results.
I have another posibillity to avoid the second query?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to filter on this new 'ord' attribute.  I dont understand you "another thing" - what exactly are you referring to...?

Comment: To display the elements i have the limit (0, 20). To display the pagination A B C etc. I need to search in all results so I need to make another query

Comment: regarding the filter I`m wondering if I can make the filter directly in Query; $result = $cl->Query( "$search first_letter ^A")

Comment: YEs you, need a second query. http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#clustering Example> http://www.nearby.org.uk/sphinx/search-example6-withcomments.phps

Comment: You could enable prefix searching http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-min-prefix-len but dont see its worth the bother. You need the attribute anyway for the group-by. PLus also its harder to do your 'other'/*

Comment: Another thing.
In this moment the pagination has this form : " + 0 1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 A B C.... So my question is if I can group all special characters in "*" group so the pagination should become * 1 2 3..A B C.. In MySql I made the select based on REGEXP '[[:alnum:]]'

Comment: sql_query = SELECT id, name, ORD(LEFT(UPPER(name), 1)) AS first_letter

Comment: My original answer deals with it. Using the IF() function.

Comment: Hi! $cl->setFilter('ord',array(ord('A'))); works fine with one exception : If the first letter is a multi-byte character, for example : $cl->setFilter('ord',array(ord('Á'))); I have sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8; charset_type = utf-8

Comment: Well can read how the mysql 'multi-byte' handling works here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_ord would need to emulate the same in php. it appears mysqls ASCII function more directly corresponds to phps ORD function